# Find and copy file in same directory where files were found with .bk extension

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Let say I have .netrc files in my Unix system

```
/home/abc/.netrc
/home/xyz/.netrc
...
...
/use/.nitric
```

Using find command how I can make the backup of these files in same directories where files were found

```
find / -name "netrc" -exec cp {} <should be found filepath filename.bk> \;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just specify the target name, like this:

```
find / -name '.netrc' -execdir cp -a {} {}.bk \;
```

Notice you can use `{}` multiple times. Also, we use the `execdir` action here, because it's safer and recommended over `exec`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me

find / -name ".netrc" | xargs -I {} cp {} {}.bk

Comment: That works, but for a more efficient solution check my answer. You don't really need xargs here (an external tool called for each file).